# How to compare the month parts of two dates?

Tags: sql, cakephp, cakephp-3.0, query-builder

I am trying to query query the current month, here is my query:

```
 $clients = $this->Clients;
    $query = $clients->find();

    if($this->Auth->user('role') !== 'admin'){
        $query->where(['user_id =' => $this->Auth->user('id')]);
        $query->where(['MONTH(dob) = ' => 'EXTRACT(month FROM (NOW()))']);

        $query->order(['dob' => 'ASC']);

    }
```

It returns 0 records (my field is a date type), however this query in phpmyadmin works:

```
SELECT * FROM `clients` WHERE MONTH(dob) = EXTRACT(month FROM (NOW()))
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just look at the actual generated query (check out your DBMS query log, or try [**DebugKit**](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/debug-kit.html)), it will look different, as the right hand side value in a `key => value` condition set is subject to parameter-binding/casting/quoting/escaping. In your case it will be treated as a string, so the condition will finally look something like:

```sql
WHERE MONTH(dob) = 'EXTRACT(month FROM (NOW()))'
```

That will of course not match anything.

You could pass the whole SQL snippet as a single array value, or as an expression object, that way it would be inserted into the query as is (do not insert user values that way, that would create an SQL injection vulnerability!), but I'd suggest to use portable function expressions instead.

CakePHP ships with functions expressions for `EXTRACT` and `NOW`, so you can simply do something like:

```
use Cake\Database\Expression\IdentifierExpression;
use Cake\Database\Expression\QueryExpression;
use Cake\ORM\Query;

// ...

$query->where(function (QueryExpression $exp, Query $query) {
    return $exp->eq(
        $query->func()->extract('MONTH', new IdentifierExpression('dob')),
        $query->func()->extract('MONTH', $query->func()->now())
    );
});
```

Looks a bit complicated, but it's worth it, it's cross DBMS portable as well as auto-quoting compatible. The generated SQL will look something like

```
WHERE EXTRACT(MONTH FROM (dob)) = (EXTRACT(MONTH FROM (NOW())))
```

See also

- **[Cookbook > Database Access & ORM > Query Builder > Advanced Conditions](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/query-builder.html#advanced-conditions)**
- **[Cookbook > Database Access & ORM > Query Builder > Using SQL Functions](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/query-builder.html#using-sql-functions)**
- **[API > \Cake\Database\Expression\QueryExpression::eq()](https://api.cakephp.org/3.3/class-Cake.Database.Expression.QueryExpression.html#_eq)**
- **[API > \Cake\Database\FunctionsBuilder::extract()](https://api.cakephp.org/3.3/class-Cake.Database.FunctionsBuilder.html#_extract)**
- **[API > \Cake\Database\FunctionsBuilder::now()](https://api.cakephp.org/3.3/class-Cake.Database.FunctionsBuilder.html#_now)**

Comment: Thanks, there is a lot of great info here but when I try your query, I get this error: "message": "Call to a member function func() on null"

Comment: I would be very surprised if that error really happened with the exact code above, as the value passed to the second argument of the closure is `$this`. If it were `null`, it would mean the object itself that calls the function, doesn't exist (I've already seen weirder quirks in PHP though). In any case, without seeing all the code, the stacktrace, knowing the exact CakePHP version, there's little to nothing I could do for you here in the comments. @bstras21

Comment: Actually it was my fault in a misspelling. Your code did work, thanks!